# How to disable alert sounds on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, settings

This question is similar to:
[Disable alert sounds on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282170/disable-alert-sounds-on-ubuntu-20-04/1283678#1283678)

In Ubuntu 18.04, one could disable alert sounds directly in the settings. In Ubuntu 20.04, in the settings you can change the alert sound, but you cannot disable it.

**How can you disable alert sounds in Ubuntu 20.04?**

I tried:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false
```

and

```
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false
```

It did not change anything. I am testing this with a usb-stick (plugging in and ejecting).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ah, I found it!

Go to Settings → *Sound* and edit the bar for *System Sounds* under the header *Volume Levels*.

For me, it was first set to 0, but somehow didn't register. After setting it louder and then muting it again it worked as required.

[image: system settings: sound]

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the slider is set to 0 by default, but the actual volume is somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 7):

Do you try `dconf editor` package?

You can install `sudo apt install dconf-editor` or via Ubuntu Software Center!

[More Info...](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/03/disable-mute-alert-sound-ubuntu-19-04/)