# Turn off error sound on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound

How do I turn off the Ubuntu error sound (especially on the terminal) in Ubuntu 20.04?

Particularly `Settings -> Sound` provides options for alert sound type but no options for alert volume.

[image]

Comment: [This may help](https://askubuntu.com/a/1283774/1222991) 

Comment: IT is all or nothing: you turn off any system sound, but you cannot selectively turn off specific sounds, unless probably by replacing the sound files by a silent file.